# Logging every message received in WCF REST

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to log every message I receive via my wcf rest webservice. Something like overloading an "onmessagereceive" event. Is that possible? I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Does [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx) help you? Found by googling "wcf tracing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a message inspector for it. The blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx has an example on how to do that.